# Elasticsearch on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS: does not have a Release file

Tags: elasticsearch, ubuntu-18.04, apt

I am trying to install [ELK](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elk-stack) according to [the official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.2/deb.html#deb-repo). I am behind a corporate firewall using its own certificate. Hence, during the first step, I am adding the public key using the `--no-check-certificate` option of [Wget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget).

However, after adding the repository to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list`, I get the following error running `#apt-get update` (as root):

```
cd ~
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elasticsearch
```

Output:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Ign:4 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable InRelease
Err:5 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable Release
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 151.101.14.222 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

I tried adding `[trusted=yes]` to the `.list` file:

deb [trusted=yes] https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main

This, however, leads to even more errors while trying to update apt:

Ign:1 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable InRelease
Ign:2 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable Release
Ign:3 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main all Packages
Ign:4 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main amd64 Packages
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:6 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main Translation-en_US
Ign:7 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main Translation-en
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Ign:9 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:10 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main all c-n-f Metadata
Hit:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Ign:3 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main all Packages
Ign:4 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main amd64 Packages
Ign:6 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main Translation-en_US
Ign:7 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main Translation-en
Ign:9 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:10 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main all c-n-f Metadata
Ign:3 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main all Packages
Ign:4 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main amd64 Packages
Ign:6 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main Translation-en_US
Ign:7 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main Translation-en
Ign:9 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:10 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main all c-n-f Metadata
Ign:3 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main all Packages
Ign:4 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main amd64 Packages
Ign:6 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main Translation-en_US
Ign:7 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main Translation-en
Ign:9 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:10 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main all c-n-f Metadata
Ign:3 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main all Packages
Ign:4 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main amd64 Packages
Ign:6 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main Translation-en_US
Ign:7 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main Translation-en
Ign:9 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:10 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main all c-n-f Metadata
Ign:3 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main all Packages
Ign:4 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main amd64 Packages
Ign:6 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main Translation-en_US
Ign:7 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main Translation-en
Ign:9 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:10 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main all c-n-f Metadata
Ign:3 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main all Packages
Err:4 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main amd64 Packages
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 151.101.14.222 443]
Ign:6 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main Translation-en_US
Ign:7 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main Translation-en
Ign:9 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:10 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable/main all c-n-f Metadata
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 151.101.14.222 443]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Have you checked for any typos or duplication? For example, I encountered a similar issue installing Elasticsearch. I entered the following commands: echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.xapt stable main" |
sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elasticsearch - and later discovered I was  missing out a "/" in the first command. This triggered an error like the one above. It's worth checking /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list - to see what you've got in there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it: by extracting the SSL certificate which was imposed by the corporate firewall and adding it to the list of trusted certificates, I was resolved the issue:

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -showcerts -servername -connect github.com:443 2>/dev/null  | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p'  >> $(curl-config --ca)
```

Comment: Thanks for this post, I am having the same issue. However, when executing the command I am getting the following:
```echo -n | openssl s_client -showcerts -servername -connect github.com:443 2>/dev/null  | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p'  >> "$(curl-config --ca)"
bash: $(curl-config --ca): No such file or directory
```. Do you have an idea how to fix it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I inflicted this on myself by changing permissions within `/etc/ssl` with commands that resulted in roughly

```
chmod 710 /etc/ssl/*/
chmod 400 /etc/ssl/private/*
```

Very inconvenient to debug, hope this helps some future fat-fingered fellow.

Answer (score -2):

WARNING:: Not a recommended way and its highly insecure to do this:

I had to do skip the GPG signature verification in order to proceed.

To add the "no-verify" option when using apt to install or update packages, you can follow these steps:

Open the /etc/apt/sources.list file in a text editor using the command:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list/elastic-7.x.list
```

Locate the line that corresponds to the Elastic repository entry. It will look similar to:

```
deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main
```

Modify the line by appending [trusted=yes] to the end. The modified line should look like this:

```
deb [trusted=yes] https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main
```

The `trusted=yes` option `bypasses` the GPG signature verification during package installation or update.

Now, when you use apt commands to install or update packages from the Elastic repository, the GPG signature verification will be skipped, and the "no-verify" behavior will be enabled.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the latest policies since your answer (other than the warning at the top) appears likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). As a heads-up, [posting of AI-generated content is not permitted on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831), even if it helped you personally.

Comment: If you used an AI tool for assistance on this answer, could I ask you to (1) Reply in a comment here confirming that it was AI-generated, along with what tool (e.g., ChatGPT, Bing Chat, Copilot, etc.) -- We're compiling data on AI-assisted answers and could use your help. (2) After commenting, I recommend deleting your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds: The first 2-3 sentences were probably not generated by ChatGPT. But it only strengthen the case: One of the parts were plagiarised. It is also a late answer, the preferred place for plagiarisers.

Comment: What tool was used to generate the last part?

Comment: Hello, even though I used chatgpt to write the answer, ChatGPT did not suggest me this answer. I told ChatGPT to compose this by giving the answer, I have been using `trusted=yes` for the same issue for many years.